# Partial string matching in python

Tags: python, string

I have an section id `A00-A09`. Anything like `A01`, `A01.01`, `A02` till `A09.09` should be
classified under this section id. How can i do this in Python?  At the moment I can only match string with exact character.

Comment: Check the `re` module, regex

Comment: @sshashank124 You mean the `re` module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` with re module:

```
re.findall('A0[0-9].0[0-9]|A0[0-9]','A01')
```

output:

```
['A01']
```

Non occurance:

```
re.findall('A0[0-9].0[0-9]|A0[0-9]','A11')
```

output:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.match()` to check this. here is an example:

```
import re

section_id = "A01.09"
if re.match("^A0[0-9](\.0[0-9])?$", section_id):
    print "yes"
```

Here the regex means `A0X` is mandatory, and `.0X` is optional. `X` is from `0-9`.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the section id and compare:

```
sid = "A00-A09"

def under_sid(ssid, sid):
    sid_start, sid_end = sid.split("-")
    return ssid[:3] >= sid_start and ssid[:3] <= sid_end

for i in ["A01", "A01.01", "A02", "A09.09"]:
    assert under_sid(i, sid)

for i in ["B01", "A22.01", "A93", "A19.09"]:
    assert not under_sid(i, sid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do partial matches using [`startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). Assuming the full id is always in a `X12.Y34` - each part is a letter and two numbers, separated by `.` or `-` (or any character):

```
>>> id = 'A03.A07'
>>> section_id = id[:3]
>>> section_id 
'A03'
>>> id.startswith('A03')
True
>>> id.startswith('A07')
False  # so won't match with the subsection.
>>> sub_section_id = id[-3:]
>>> sub_section_id 
'A07'
```

And you can convert it to [uppercase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) if the input can sometimes be lowercase.